# JQuery-UI Sortable Bootstrap Last col bug

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jquery-ui sortable in a boostrap3 grid layout:

```
<section class="slice">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="blockcontainer">
            <div class="block col-md-3">A</div> 
            <div class="block col-md-3">B</div> 
            <div class="block col-md-3">C</div> 
            <div class="block col-md-3">D</div> 
            <div class="block col-md-12 pull-left">E</div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99on7Lyt/show/

When I drag&drop the last col-md (D in the example) it starts moving in a wrong position, from the second row instead of the upper right corner.
All other cols works fine. 
How can i fix?

Edit: The bug is only on Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add a padding on blockcontainer id:

```
#blockcontainer{
       padding:5px;    
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle with the fix:
http://jsfiddle.net/99on7Lyt/9/show/